# How to mock System.getenv() in JUnit [Powermock + Parameterized]

Tags: mockito, junit4, spring-test, powermockito

How to mock "System.getenv("...")" in JUnit.

Currently I am doing:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class TestClass extends BaseTest {

    public TestClass(String testCase) {
        this.testCase = testCase;
    }

    @Before
    @Override
    public final void initTable() throws Throwable {
        super.initTable();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class); 
        PowerMockito.when(System.getenv("ENV_VAR1")).thenReturn("1234");       
    }
...
}
```

I am using both PowerMock and Parameterizedrunner.

I am getting below exception for line:

```
PowerMockito.when(System.getenv("ENV_VAR1")).thenReturn("1234");
```

Exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
'afterPropertiesSet' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
***
```

Comment: I would really advise to not do things this way. Change your production code to **not** use System.getenv() (at least not directly); and avoid all that (crazy) working around stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
>   Use the @PrepareForTest({ClassThatCallsTheSystemClass.class}) annotation at the class-level of the test case.

Example with using EasyMock

```
public class SystemClassUser {

public String performEncode() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return URLEncoder.encode("string", "enc");
}
  }
```

And test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest( { SystemClassUser.class })
   public class SystemClassUserTest {

@Test
public void assertThatMockingOfNonFinalSystemClassesWorks() throws Exception {
    mockStatic(URLEncoder.class);

    expect(URLEncoder.encode("string", "enc")).andReturn("something");
    replayAll();

    assertEquals("something", new SystemClassUser().performEncode());

    verifyAll();
}
 }
```

From:
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockSystem

So, you should add a class that uses the `System.getenv`, not the `System` class to `@PrepareForTest`.

This [post](https://blog.jayway.com/2009/05/17/mocking-static-methods-in-java-system-classes/) explains why it should be done in such way.

Also, I'd like to recommend to use the [System Rules library](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) for your case. It has a good way to [stub environment variables](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/#EnvironmentVariables). PowerMock modifies a class byte code, so it makes test slowly. And even if it not modify a class it at least read class from disk.

Comment: Using System rules solved the issue.                                                 
Just want some more info:
1. When we set the variable in Test cases, will it stay forever in System environment or it stays only during test execution. 
2. If it stays forever, Can we unset it?

Comment: from documentation: "It does all the tedious work for setting environment variables and reverts your changes after the test." so `EnvironmentVariables` will unset all values that you set in test.